# why doesnt this javascript cookie code work?

Tags: javascript, function, cookies

SEE http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
Full working code there. (except the logout, which is easy - just reset cookie to expire in 0 seconds.)

Comment: Because it is unreadable by both man and machine

Comment: I don't take the time to try to read and understand minified code.  Not many people will.

Comment: Minified, unreadable and ridiculous. `today.setTime(today.getTime())` is how they set the clocks in the [tautology club](http://xkcd.com/703/).

Comment: well the code itself works perfectly, but i took it out of the external javascript file and pasted it into the body. and it just stoped working. maybe it really is because of it being minified..

Comment: @lonesomedaywell - its not so ridiculous, since it worked great and still works as long as it is in an external file!

Comment: @jony The fact that it worked in some way doesn't stop it being ridiculous. There are many far superior Javascript libraries in existence – for goodness' sake use one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a look at `}` causes a syntax error after the first today.toGMTString();

where is the `setCookie` function? this also could be a reason that it dose not work.

also `c_name` is not defined

Comment: well i took the function name out so that it would start instantly, without any onload events. The problem resided in the javascript being extremely minified. With normal compression it work within the page code (instead of working just as an external script).

Comment: thanks david for the atention. i will post the fixed code as a fully working example.

Comment: quirksmode cookie script is good http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script

Comment: actual the reason it wasnt working was really because it was unredable by both man and machine. i compressed it too much. please pardon my "noobidity" and thanks for all the pieces of advise!

Comment: @jony if your looking for a good compressor i recommend http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs

Answer (score 0):

The code `<BODY onLoad="javascript:checkCookie();">foo</body>` instructs the script engine to call the `checkCookie` function, which does not appear in your code. You must include it in your page, otherwise it can't work...

Also, I would advise you to use a decent tool to check for syntax
 errors in scripts, like Firebug or the Chrome Developer Tools. We all do it, it really saves a lot of time when debugging!